# Tomcat JNDI: NameNotFoundException DefaultManagedExecutorService and concurrent/ThreadPool

Tags: tomcat, jndi

I am running Tomcat 8.5 on Windows 7 for testing, and cannot use a ManagedExecutorService.
Tried via resource injection and code:

```
ManagedExecutorService executorService = (ManagedExecutorService)
                       ctx.lookup("java:comp/DefaultManagedExecutorService");
ManagedExecutorService executorService = (ManagedExecutorService)
                       ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/concurrent/ThreadPool");
```

Both got:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [concurrent/ThreadPool] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [concurrent].

Tomcat installed using default installer.
Tomcat [conf files](http://pastebin.com/3nHPK9BZ)